# Bash string literal comparison to variable failing

Tags: bash

I have the following simple bash code to test string comparison:

```
#!/bin/sh

BRANCH="master"

echo $ref

if [[ "$ref" = "refs/heads/$BRANCH" ]]
then
    echo "Matches"
else
    echo "Do not match"
fi
```

When I ran the code using `export ref=/refs/heads/master && . sample` I get the following result:

```
/refs/heads/master
Do not match
```

What may be causing the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is causing the problem is the missing slash in your test: `/refs/heads/master` is not equal to `refs/heads/master`!